# How to scrape user details from Instagram?

Tags: python-3.x, instagram-api

I have a list of Instagram user IDs which I want to have the user details pulled for. I am using this url `https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/{user_id}/info/`, but after processing few hundred requests, I get 400 response code i.e. (Account is temporarily blocked). Is there any way to avoid this? Your suggestions will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: "Account is temporarily blocked" This suggests that your account is being flagged for excessive use.

Comment: I am already using proxies. And doing this with selenium will be so slow. The point it's the account that is being blocked and not the IP

Comment: @Retic is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: Have you tried waiting a few minutes after querying 100 entries or so? You are apparently reaching the rate limit.

Comment: I have included different delay times. Can we go 1-1 and I'll share with you the logic I am using? Thanks

Comment: I doubt you are going to find a solution to this kind of request throttling. you will need to mimic a user, users don't request a couple hundred profiles at a time. Instagram may provide provision for this via some paid service?

Comment: I am planning to make 2000-3000 requests in 24 hours. Is that beyond the limits imposed by IG?